# Node serving session cookies instead of using maxAge

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am using code from [Stripe's rocket rides](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides/blob/master/server/app.js) to serve cookies and remember users:

```js
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('cookie-session');

// ...

const app = express();

// Enable sessions using encrypted cookies
app.use(cookieParser(config.secret));
app.use(
  session({
    // cookie expiration: 90 days
    cookie: {maxAge: 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000},
    secret: config.secret,
    signed: true,
    resave: true,
  })
);
```

The problem is that the cookies served are session cookies (I inspected them with Chromium Developer Tools) and deleted when the browser window closes. I checked that the live server of Rocket Rides also serves session cookies.

How can I enforce the `maxAge` for the cookie to persist for 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this.

```
app.use(cookieParser(config.secret));
app.use(
  session({
     // Cookie Options
    maxAge: 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    secret: config.secret,
    signed: true,
    resave: true,
  })
);
```